# Updating Brew error on Mac OS X

Tags: homebrew

I am trying to update brew on my Mac OS X machine so I can update php.  However, when trying to run `brew install`, I get this error:

```
error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge:
    Library/Homebrew/extend/enumerable.rb
Please move or remove them before you can merge.
Aborting
Error: Failure while executing: git pull --quiet origin refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

brew doctor:

Warning: Broken symlinks were found. Remove them with `brew prune`:
  /usr/local/bin/wget
  /usr/local/share/man/man1/wget.1
  /usr/local/Library/LinkedKegs/wget

Answer (score 25):

Check the solution here
https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/21002

in Short

```
cd /usr/local
git status
git reset --hard origin/master
git clean -df
```

Comment: This worked for me. However, I needed to set my permissions correctly using `sudo chown -R $USER:admin /usr/local` before running these commands, as mentioned by mistydemeo.

Answer (score 6):

Type `brew doctor` and do what it tells you.

Comment: This might technically be an answer, but it isn't much of one. Could you flesh it out with specific instructions based on the output?

Answer (score 0):

`brew install` is not what you are looking for.  I believe if you do this

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

You should be good.  If you want more info you should check here https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/share/doc/homebrew/FAQ.md#faq

Comment: I enjoy throwing `brew outdated` after `brew update` just to see what is about to be upgraded.

Comment: I am running brew update, not brew install.  I'm still getting this error

Comment: @GrahamPerks that is in the link, but I omitted it from my answer for brevity as the information wasn't relevant to solving the issue.  I agree that it is generally very good practice to do so

Comment: @user1072337 ok, that changes things to an extent.  I'll look into it.

Comment: brew update will give the same error, you need to run brew upgrade first